# Setting Shadow of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a shadow like, when you get it from :

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Does anybody knows the source code from this?
Or how I can achieve that I only have the shadow at the bottom of my layout and not around it?

Comment: Give some bottom padding using this background. It will give you shadow effect

Comment: [This](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/dialog_full_holo_light.9.png) is the drawable you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two way:

1) Add **shadow.xml** or **shadow.png** to your **drawable** and use it in your layout

**shadow.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#43000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp">
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#00000000"
                android:startColor="#10000000" />

            <size android:height="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

example of **your_layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

2) another way is **Workaround**

most of the shadow is actually below the view, a subtle shadow is also above. A workaround might be using a very high value for elevation, like 40dp: the bottom part is going to be hidden due to your layout, while the top is going to be expanded and look like a common shadow.

In either case, you do not have control over the elevation value in dp, in the sense that you can't be sure your shadow is equivalent to the one cast by android:elevation=4dp.

Comment: This is not really a shadow

Comment: another option is set card_view:cardElevation in cardview android

Answer (score 1):

You can use 9 Patch shadow generator as background of layout from below link.

[Shadow generator](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

Answer (score 0):

shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#00AAAAAA" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#10AAAAAA" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#20AAAAAA" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#30AAAAAA" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#50AAAAAA" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Use this as background of whole layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<---Describe your whole layout here>

</LinearLayout>
```